# Is it "some MOUSE" or "Some MICE"?

Tags: nouns, countable-nouns

I would like to ask a grammatical question in the following sentence. "I was happily munching away when some mouse spilled coffee on me." Why it says some mouse? But not some mice?

Comment: Perhaps there was only one mouse? And you hadn't been introduced?

Comment: Some chickens! Some necks?

Comment: Some idiot, some wazzock, some b *st *rd?